# How can i set background app icon in ios?

Tags: react-native

I am creating a new react native application. I set the app icon in Xcode but when I open the background apps my icon seems unset.
But in the main menu, it seems normal.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you added all the app icons?

Comment: Did you try building in production?

Comment: @Sunny yea i added all the icons

Comment: @Auticcat yea i did it many times but i donno why it fixed now. Thanks for the comments

Comment: I think its about the clean project and re build again thanks for @Auticcat

Comment: Any Bug → Clean → Build → Repeat